# Do biotin supplements increase hair growth and strength?

Tags: medical-science, hair

There many websites selling biotin suplements claiming that they will make hair grow stronger and faster. Here are two examples:

[Hair Growth Vitamin](http://www.hairgrowthvitaminsdirect.com/biotin-hair-growth/)

Bio-info Hair Growth

Biotin deficency is shown to cause some problems [including hair loss](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/druginfo/natural/313.html).

But a deficiency must be extremely rare: recommended doses vary up to 25mcg, which is easily gotten from an egg white. Supplements are generally sold with 3000-5000mcg per capsule.

**Do biotin supplements increase hair growth and strength?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Biotin deficiency [seems indeed to be rare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biotin_deficiency). As with almost all vitamin supplementation, it's probably better to not take any unless you know you have a specific deficiency.

As expected, the sites you provide are full in anecdotal evidence and short on hard evidence, so stick with the Null Hypothesis until proven otherwise.

**Very** much [recommended reading on the vitamin supplementation issue](http://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/index.php/another-negative-study-of-vitamins/)